# Joining together results of two select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have the following schema and I am just stuck on one particular part.

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(128), Postcode VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE Branches (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(128), Postcode VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE Postcode_States (ID INT, State VARCHAR(128), Postcode VARCHAR(10));


SELECT S.Name AS SupplierName, PS.State AS SupplierState
FROM Suppliers AS S 
LEFT JOIN Postcode_States PS ON S.Postcode = PS.Postcode;

SELECT B.Name AS BranchName, PS.State AS BranchCounty
FROM Branches AS B 
LEFT JOIN Postcode_States PS ON B.Postcode = PS.Postcode;
```

I have three tables, Suppliers, Branches and Postcode_States. I have selected all the Suppliers and their states joined on postcode in one query and all the Branches and their states joined on postcode in another query. Can anyone give me any guidance on how I could combine these two queries so that I could return all the Suppliers and Branches with the same state? Thanks

Sample data and requested query output

[image]

Comment: sample data an expected output will be useful here

Comment: The same state as what? You're returning all the Suppliers at the moment.

Comment: I want to return a rows containing Supplier Names and Branch names where the state is the same

Comment: @user1501171 . . . What is Texas the same state as?

Answer (score 0):

You can join:

```
select s.name, b.name, p.state
from suppliers s
inner join branches  b on b.postcode = s.postcode
inner join postcodes p on p.postcode = s.postcode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want states with more than one supplier, you can use window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.name, b.name, p.state,
             count(*) over (partition by state) as cnt
      from suppliers s join
           branches b
           on b.postcode = s.postcode join
           postcodes p
           on p.postcode = s.postcode
     ) s
where cnt >= 2
order by cnt desc, state;
```

This doesn't return Texas, but your question suggests that you want duplicates.